# Building in Nant script using msbuild giving error because of the dash

Tags: msbuild, nant

I'm using an Nant build script which builds my project using msbuild. The problem, my solution is called "something - something.sln" and it's giving an error because of the space and the dash. 
How could I solve this without changing the solution?

My Nant script:

```
   <property name="solution.name"       value="Account – Bulk Process.sln" />    

   <property name="build.item" value="${build.dir}\${solution.name}" />
    <property name="config.type"        value="Debug" />
    <property name="target"                 value="clean" />
    <msbuild project="${build.item}" target="${target}" verbose="${verbose}" failonerror="true">
      <property name="Configuration" value="${config.type}" verbose="${verbose}" />
    </msbuild>
```

Error:

```
[echo] Task execution started at : 01/04/2015 14:55:18
 [echo] Task execution finished at : 01/04/2015 14:55:18
  [msbuild] Starting MSBuild...
  [msbuild] Starting 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe (@"C:\Users\...")' in 'C:\Dev\Teley\Account – Bulk Process'
  [msbuild] MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.
  [msbuild] Switch: C:\Dev\Teley\Account ƒ?" Bulk Process.sln
```

Comment: What error is it giving?  Whilst none of our .sln files contain " - " in their names, the paths leading to some of them do and we don't see issues.

Comment: Added some extra code